# I am looking for a flash or javascript slideshow like the link below

Tags: javascript, flash, gallery

http://www.hotelterrajacksonhole.com

I have searched, but haven't found any galleries that would animate the images in a way similar to the above link.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure this can be done with jquery, but I don't know any "plugins" that do this automatically, and I don't think you will easily find any that suit your specific needs because there are too many variables (image sizes, number of images in one slide, layout of images on slide, different animations and transitions, focus of images (should not disappear in animation, see the girl in example), etc.)

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right, after searching all morning, I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty cool effect but I agree with @Willem you won't find any simple plug-in-play solution. Even looking at how the homepage-winter.swf file is set up it's totally custom and has no reusable parts as it's using frame-based animation (over 500 frames).

Answer (score 0):

Some places to look for flash galleries are FlashLoaded.com , FlashDen.com and Ultrashock.com
You will not find an exact match to the one listed above. It appears to have been custom work. But if you are looking for a slide show component those three sites have what you are looking for.